# C# Vlc wrapper in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc, libvlc, ip-camera

I have been following this little [8min tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk6vAyIZZ0A&list=PLc2UaWzFQrPN7XNq2mAkVdsMkRCI0BMML&index=2).

I am fairly new to C# but mostly understand what is going on. The only piece I don't understand is at 7:11. He appears to pull in a namespace (or variable) that is not in scope. I am assuming it is part of the vlc wrapper because of this line:

```
 video.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryneeded += MediaPlayer_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded;
```

---

Everything you said worked!

You wouldn't happen to know why these are giving me errors would you? I don't see these listed in the class anymore. I'm assuming the same method was just renamed something different?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video does not show all parts of the project. The `MainWindow.xaml` file that is not shown in the video contains a `VlcControl` from the `Vlc.DotNet.Wpf` NuGet package. This control is used to display the actual video content in the main window. It is declared in XAML like this:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf">
   <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="video"/>
</Window>
```

The `vlc` prefix is just the XAML namespace to access the control. The `x:Name` attribute defines the name of the instance. Consequently, the `video` in code-behind is just the `VlcControl` instance in the window.

However you will still not be anle to access the `MediaPlayer` property of `video`, because in the version 3.0.0 the `VlcControl` for WPF [was rewritten](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/commit/516cca3d97d3cb6bde69af33ca85753737aef200#diff-2343f94427b09225f9b76d0d90e4771cL7) and the `MediaPlayer` property was moved. You now access it like this:

```
video.SourceProvider.MediaPlayer
```

The `VlcLibDirectoryNeeded` event shown in the video is only present in the WinForms `VlcControl`, it was removed from the WPF variant when it was rewritten.

Comment: You are amazing! I knew there had to be something missing like this. I have only just started playing with xaml, WPF, and c#. I've strictly done console command stuff in c and c++. Is the idea to just add your provided lines of code in the XAML? If I do that I get a "property content is set more than once." Either way thank you! I would have never figured that out. I am amazing you knew that.

Comment: @BDHys You can add this code, but that willl not be enough. The tutorial shows the user interface in the beginning and there are other controls too, that are used in the sample code, but if you are very new to WPF it may not be easy to recreate that quickly. I think you should first learn about how to use the built-in control to compose a user interface and build up on that. By the way, you mot probably get that error, because a `Window` can only host a single element and you already had one in there.

Comment: @BDHsy To host multiple controls you have to use one of the WPF [panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview#user-interface-panels). For example, put your controls in a `StackPanel` and put the `StackPanel` in your window, but that is far out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I was able to get what you added to work finally. I think I have the other controls set up too. I am just stuck on the fact that VlcLibDirectoryNeeded and EndInit are no longer part of the WPF libraries. I'm stuck on how to recreate this and any example codes use these in their example. 

I was just trying to create a simple  C# Onvif GUI that uses UDP for a school assignment. What a nightmare this has turned out to be.

Comment: @BDHys You could try to use an older version before 3.0.0 and test if that works. That at least has all properties, methods and events of the tutorial, but do not forget to make backup of your current work, in case it does not work.

Comment: Thank you! I have everything running. Really appreciate your help. Now to figure out how to use the VLC wrapper to stream in UDP. Thanks for your help.